# clarification on footnote option in the output proc print

Tags: sas

**Question: I do not understand why the footnote3 and footnote4 do not shown in the output?**

```
footnote1 ‘Sales Report for Last Month’;
footnote2 ‘Selected Products Only’;
footnote3 ‘All Regions’;
footnote4 ‘All Figures in Thousands of Dollars’;
proc print data = sashelp.cars;
footnote2 ‘All Products’;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a FOOTNOTE statement is specified for a given line, it cancels the previous FOOTNOTE statement for that line and for all footnote lines with higher numbers.

So, the footnote2 in your proc print cancels footnote3 and 4.

For example, the simple statement

> footnote;

is used to delete all previous defined footnotes.
For titles this is also true.

Comment: Hi is there any reference i can look at? as i cannot find in language reference: dictionary. Many thanks

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214615.htm

under details

Comment: One point worth mentioning here is that footnote statements are global -even if you put one in the middle of a proc, it will apply to all all subsequent proc output until cancelled with a null footnote statement.